How to make a textarea expand vertically to fill all rows in a table?
I'm trying to create a table with a corresponding textarea for notes in each row. Additionally, I have a toggle switch that, when enabled, hides all but the first textarea and makes the first textarea expand to fill the space of all rows combined.
Here is the HTML and JavaScript code I am using (JS Fiddle):


document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("change", e => {
     const isChecked = e.target.checked;
     const notes = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

     for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
         const note = notes[i];
         const parentCell = note.closest("td");

         if (i !== 0) {
             parentCell.hidden = isChecked;
         } else {
             parentCell.rowSpan = isChecked ? notes.length : 1;
         }
     }
 });
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <table class="table">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Cat</th>
               <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Luna</td>
               <td>
                  <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Milo</td>
               <td>
                  <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Oscar</td>
               <td>
                  <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Bella</td>
               <td>
                  <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
         <label class="form-check-label">Toggle single textarea</label>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>



When I toggle the checkbox, the first textarea does not expand to fill the height of all the rows. How can I make the first textarea stretch to occupy the space of all rows combined when the checkbox is checked?
The only way to make it work is set (a) the height of the first textarea to 100% and (b) its parent td a fixed height, like 200px, but I can't use a hardcoded height for the td since I don't know in advance how many rows the table will have.

This UX sounds a bit sketchy. What if the table is taller than the screen? I suggest that you use a modal if you want a larger text area, or simply disable the other textareas rather than hiding them.

Only row 0's textarea?
if (isChecked) notes[0].setAttribute('rows', 10);
else  notes[0].removeAttribute('rows');



document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("change", e => {
  const isChecked = e.target.checked;
  const notes = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
  if (isChecked) notes[0].setAttribute('rows', 10);
  else  notes[0].removeAttribute('rows');
  for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    const note = notes[i];
    const parentCell = note.closest("td");

    if (i !== 0) {
      parentCell.hidden = isChecked;
    } else {
      parentCell.rowSpan = isChecked ? notes.length : 1;
    }
  }
});
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cat</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Luna</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milo</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Oscar</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bella</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
    <label class="form-check-label">Toggle single textarea</label>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



Or with JS/css
notes[0].classList.toggle('tall', isChecked);

.tall {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}



document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("change", e => {
  const isChecked = e.target.checked;
  const notes = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
  notes[0].classList.toggle('tall', isChecked);

  for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    const note = notes[i];
    const parentCell = note.closest("td");
    if (i !== 0) {
      parentCell.hidden = isChecked;
    } else {
      parentCell.rowSpan = isChecked ? notes.length : 1;
    }
  }
});
.tall {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cat</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Luna</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milo</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Oscar</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bella</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
    <label class="form-check-label">Toggle single textarea</label>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>




Thank you for your answer! However, the issue with this approach is that the height of the first textarea is fixed to 10 rows (or notes.length if we want it to be adaptive based on the number of table rows). This creates a problem because the height of one textarea row does not scale proportionally to the height of one table row. As a result, for a larger number of table rows, for example, 10 rows, the textarea only spans approximately 6 rows instead of all 10. As for the second approach using JS and the tall class, it can't work since it's hardcoded and the number of table rows is fixed.

Then the other answer seems useful

Not too sure if i understood, but here is a naive way to update the first found textarea's height if isChecked is true: https://jsfiddle.net/ra9Lu820/


document
  .querySelector("input[type=checkbox]")
  .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    const notes = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
    let notesH = 0;//init notesH
    for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      const note = notes[i];
      notesH = notesH + note.offsetHeight;//add textareas heights
      const parentCell = note.closest("td");

      if (i !== 0) {
        parentCell.hidden = isChecked;
      } else {
        parentCell.rowSpan = isChecked ? notes.length : 1;
      }
    }
    // update first textarea'height if isChecked
    if (isChecked) document.querySelector("textarea").style.height = notesH + "px";
    else document.querySelector("textarea").style.height = 'auto';
  });
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cat</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Luna</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milo</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Oscar</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bella</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
    <label class="form-check-label">Toggle single textarea</label>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



